# Compiling with gVim not working

Tags: vim, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to compile a simple C program to test that my set-up is correct.
First I typed it with gVim and created a Makefile

Now that I have a main.c and a Makefile, I tried compiling it by using

```
:make
```

Then I get this message:

```
|| 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
|| operable program or batch file.
```

All of this under gVim.

Then to test that my makefile and make installation is working I opened Cygwin, went to the directory where my main and make files are, typed

```
$ make
```

And it compiled fine.

I am not really sure what to do next, I used to be able to run :make from gVim but that was a long time ago and I think I forgot how to set it up correctly.

---

I also have a portable gVim on my flash drive and on other computers with some other set up I can use

```
:make
```

from my own gVim.

Comment: As far as I know, your Windows GVim doesn't and can't know about your Cygwin, you must set up `make` to work in `cmd.exe`. Try `make` in `cmd.exe` and see what happens.

Comment: I see. I never thought to test it in cmd.exe. It does not work there.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was to add the PATH variables.
I feel stupid now.